# How to get property of associated table?

Tags: cakephp

I was setup cake php for website: http://bomnuocebara.com but i have error.
I have very basic question but I'm kind of stuck with the syntax here:
I have an entity query. The entity is associated to another table which has a 'name' property? (many to many association)

My `$query` looks like this when I debug it:

```
/plugins/MailCalculator/src/Controller/PostalServicesController.php (line 140)
object(MailCalculator\Model\Entity\PostalService) {

    'id' => (int) 1,
    'carrier' => 'Deutsche Post'

    },
    'modified' => null,
    '_matchingData' => [
        'Insurances' => object(MailCalculator\Model\Entity\Insurance) {

            'id' => (int) 2,
            'name' => 'Wert',
            'price' => (float) 4.3,
...
```

basically the question is, how do I get the values out from the `__matchingData array`?

I thought the syntax for it should be something like:
`$var = $query->insurance->name` or `$var = $query->insurances['name']` but both things debugged give me **'null'**

Answer (score 2):

This should work with your current results.

```
$var = $query->_matchingData['Insurances']->name
```

Note, that if you contain association to your query, it should be available also as standard property in result set.

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#filtering-by-associated-data

> The data from the association that is ‘matched’ will be available on
>   the _matchingData property of entities. If you both match and contain
>   the same association, you can expect to get both the _matchingData and
>   standard association properties in your results.